# Android- Qt - Protobuf: Compiling protobuf with ndk's prebuilt toolchains

Tags: android, c++, qt5, protocol-buffers

I'm currently porting an application written in Qt5 to Android.

I have installed Qt5 through its official installer, along with the AndroidSdk through Android Studio.

I can compile, deploy and execute a Qt5/Qml application on an Android target.

However, the application I am porting uses Protobuf, therefore I want to cross-compile this library with the compiler Qt is using to package it with my application.

I have successfully built protobuf with a standalone toolchain following this resource : https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/c/protobuf

But when using the toolchain Qt5 uses I am not able to build the protobuf library.

A sample from my application's working compile commands:

```
/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain /home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sysroot -isystem /home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem /home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem /home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/android/support/include -isystem /home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -fPIC -Wl,Bsymbolic -g -g -marm -O0 -std=gnu++1z -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CONCURRENT_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../NaioCompanion -I. -I/opt/Qt/5.13.0/android_armv7/include -I/opt/Qt/5.13.0/android_armv7/include/QtQuick -I/opt/Qt/5.13.0/android_armv7/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt/5.13.0/android_armv7/include/QtQml -I/opt/Qt/5.13.0/android_armv7/include/QtNetwork -I/opt/Qt/5.13.0/android_armv7/include/QtConcurrent -I/opt/Qt/5.13.0/android_armv7/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/Qt/5.13.0/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-clang -o xxx.o ../NaioCompanion/Publisher.cpp
```

The build script I uses for Protobuf, tweaked from the resource cited above:

```
export build_dir=`pwd`/../protobuf-for-android-with-qt5-toolchain/
export NDK=/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/
export sysroot=/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/platforms/android-21/arch-arm
export PATH=/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:$PATH
export CC="/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --sysroot=$sysroot"
export CXX="/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --sysroot=$sysroot"

./configure \
--host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--with-protoc=protoc \
--with-sysroot="$sysroot" \
--disable-shared \
--prefix="$build_dir/armeabi-v7a" \
--enable-cross-compile \
CFLAGS="-D__ANDROID_API__=21 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -march=armv7-a" \
CXXFLAGS="-frtti -fexceptions -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=21" \
LIBS="-llog -lz"

make -j2
make install
```

the output:

```
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip... arm-linux-androideabi-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains    /llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --sysroot=/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/platforms/android-21/arch-arm
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/cfv/projects/ext/try-to-build-protobuf/protobuf':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

And the `config.log` details:

```
configure:3866: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3888: /home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --sysroot=/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/platforms/android-21/arch-arm -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -march=armv7-a -nostdlib++ -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a   conftest.c -llog -lz >&5
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nostdlib++' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lunwind
/home/cfv/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lunwind
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3892: $? = 1
configure:3930: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Protocol Buffers"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "protobuf"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.6.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Protocol Buffers 3.6.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "protobuf@googlegroups.com"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "protobuf"
| #define VERSION "3.6.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3935: error: in `/home/cfv/projects/ext/try-to-build-protobuf/protobuf':
configure:3937: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I think I am missing some compiler options (I especially am suspicious about `-Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a`) but I have been struggling with it all day and this is way over my comfort zone.

Has anyone ever had a similar issue, and would be able to help me ?